# Excel Formula Concat a text cell to a hyperlink cell and keep the hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, concatenation

I have text in cell `A8` and a hyperlink in cell `B8`.

`A8` contains `Text`

`B8` contains a [Proper Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086378/how-to-create-proper-hyperlink-in-vba) with the name `HyperName` (and URL).

I want to concat the two cells in cell `C8` with a hyphen between the two components and have a hyperlink to the right of the hyphen.

When I try this, the two cells are combined, but the hyperlink disappears.

`CONCAT(A8, " - ", B8)`  - this does not work.

To work around this:

1. I copy the two cells and paste into MS Word.
2. I then in MS word convert the two cell table into text.

This looks great - the hyperlink is working, and the text to the left of the hyphen is not hyperlinked.

3. I then paste that back into a cell in Excel

The cell `C8` now has `Text - HyperName` where *only* `HyperName` has a link to the URL.

***How do I do this totally within Excel?***

Answer (score 1):

### NO VBA<sub>imperfect</sub>

What about using the [HYPERLINK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) builtin function ? That being said, it looks like you are going to have to consider expliciting your url, for example putting it in `D8`

```
= CONCAT(A8, " - ", HYPERLINK(D8, B8))
```

which will render as

```
"Text - HyperName"
```

and redirect to the url specified within `D8`. So, in conclusion, there is no way to avoid expliciting the url.

---

### VBA <sub><sup>A little bit of code, but perfectly suits you need(!)</sup></sub>

There exists a solution if you are okay with doing some [VBA](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications).

Open Microsoft Visual Basic (using the keyboard shorcut ***ALT+F11***). You will see a left panel showing the internal tree-like structure of your VBA project (*a priori* nought for the moment).

Locate the `VBAProject (<THE-NAME-OF-YOUR-FILE-HERE>)`. [Right-click it -> Insert -> Module](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/). Doing so has created an empty "script" called *Module1*.

[image]

Double-click it. On the right panel, copy/paste the following *([credits](https://superuser.com/a/908474/725634))*

```
Function EXTRACT_HYPERLINK(rng As Range) As String
     On Error Resume Next
     EXTRACT_HYPERLINK = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

Go back to the non-vba part of your excel file, save it, taking care of selecting the `xlsm` extension instead of `xlsx` (you will be alerted if you don't).

You now have your custom function (indeed, I could have chosen a name totally different than `EXTRACT_HYPERLINK`) and you can henceforth simply do

```
= CONCAT(A8, " - ", HYPERLINK(EXTRACT_HYPERLINK(B8), B8)
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you!